# What's The Proper Way To Set The Public HTML Folder Using Yii Boilerplate?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii, boilerplate

I can't find the documentation specifying how to set the public html directory. I am trying to keep all other files and folders in the site root.  Since there is a frontend and backend public html folder, I don't see how this is possible.

My Site:

```
/site/perl/
/site/www/      <-How do you get just the 2 public folders here?  
/site/.ssh
```

Yii Boilerplate:

```
runpostdeploy
yiic
/backend/
 - /config
 - /www/index.php
/frontend/
 - /config
 - /www/index.php
/common/
/console/
/tests/
```

Is the whole boilerplate project supposed to reside in the sites public html folder? I thought it was bad practice to do this.

```
*** U P D A T E ***
```

Spent most the day trying to figure out this problem. The closest thing I was able to find, was a comment on one of the Yii Framwork forum posts.  For now, I'm running Boilerplate with subdomains like they recommend in this comment.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/#c9444

I'm not sure if this is the correct way. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent most the day trying to figure out this problem. The closest thing I was able to find, was a comment on one of the Yii Framwork forum posts. For now, I'm running Boilerplate with subdomains like they recommend in this comment.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/#c9444

I'm not sure if this is the correct way. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your site public director to `frontend/www/`. The idea behind `Yii Boilerplate` `backend/www` is to have separate domain for admin options (if needed), instead of having separate module. This way you'd be able to easily have separate `CWebUser`, `Yii::app()` etc. [By the docs](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate):

*backend: the backend application which will be mainly used by site administrators to manage the whole system (avoiding admin modules at frontend application to avoid confusion)*

Comment: So I'm looking at it wrong?  The frontend is for visitors and signed in users, and the backend is suppose to be only for site administrators to manage the front end?  Like to kick a logged in user off the frontend?

Comment: If that's the case, when you split the domains for front and back, you'll need to duplicate most of the file structure to 2 different sites. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `common` directory supposed to keep shared stuff between applications. If that doesn't make sence for you, then ignore `backend` and use modules, or maybe you don't even need `backend`. It's all up to you. That structure taken from [Qiang's wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site) and mostly intended for medium or large projects.

Comment: no, I understand the structure and the programming. What didn't make sense was having 2 public roots. I ended up just creating a subdomain so I could point the fronted public as the main site, and the backend public as the sub. Yes, it's a very large, unique application, so this structure suits it best.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have two application, then you need two address. 
You can do with sub-dir like this:

```
www.site-name.com -> ../frontend/www/index.php
www.site-name.com/admin -> ../backend/www/index.php
```

Or you can use subdomain like this:

```
www.site-name.com -> ../frontend/www/index.php
admin.site-name.com -> ../backend/www/index.php
```

It's like Wordpress, if you need enter admin page, you access through address www.site-name.com/wp-admin

But, be sure you don't use the 'admin' path in your frontend if you use this alias to backend.